# How to enforce bash to recognize letters case in files names in MacOS bash?

Tags: bash, ls, macos-monterey

I bumped into the fact that MacOS GNU bash5.1.16 "ls" command doesn't differentiate between lower and upper case in the files names ( weird, I know)
e.g.

```
[17:39:28:~/Work/cloud-formation/output/templates$] ls -l Man*
-rw-r--r--  1 geoku  staff  71244 31 Jan 17:23 ManagementProd.json
-rw-r--r--  1 geoku  staff  67569 31 Jan 17:23 ManagementStage.json
```

Now, I can get the exactly same file listed with a different command:

```
[17:44:19:~/Work/cloud-formation/output/templates$] cksum ManagementStage.json Managementstage.JsOn
cksum ManagementStage.json Managementstage.JsOn
3327010753 67569 ManagementStage.json
3327010753 67569 Managementstage.JsOn
```

Is it some sort of bash settings?

Comment: That's because the filesystem macOS uses is case-insensitive (but case-preserving). bash and the various commands that access files have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Is it a type of macos bash and there's nothing to do about it? Or it's some sort of bash argument that needs setting?

Comment: It's not bash at all, it's the filesystem (or more precisely, the filesystem driver in the kernel). If any program (bash, `ls`, `cksum`, whatever) asks the kernel to open "Managementstage.JsOn", the filesystem driver does a case-insensitive lookup, finds ManagementStage.json, and opens it. As far as the filesystem is concerned, "Managementstage.JsOn" is just a funny way of writing "ManagementStage.json". If you want case sensitivity, you need to switch to a case-sensitive volume format.

Comment: @GordonDavisson When you say "case-preserving", will `mv foo Foo` change the name?

Comment: @dan Yes. In fact, if you have a file named "foo", `mv FOO Foo` will change it to "Foo" (because "FOO" matches "foo"). However, `mv Foo Foo` will not do anything, I think because `mv` notices the names match and doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out MacOS disk partitions can be created case-sensitive or not, and default is apparently the second one
Disk utility shows the options when one is trying to create a new partition
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isoG1.png)